Compare two songs content using Audio Spectogram Transformer
I'm trying to establish a similarity metric between two songs. To do this I'm using the AST model on HuggingFace. This model basically works in a way very similar to a ViT but applied to spectograms of the audio file. My basic approach is to take the output of a hidden layer for each song passed through the network, yielding a (1, 1214, 768) dim tensor.
features = model(**inputs, output_hidden_states=True).hidden_states[3].detach().cpu().numpy()[0]

I then compare the features between two songs as follows:
def compare_vecs(a, b):
    result = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)
    norm_A = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)
    norm_B = np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1)
    return np.sum(result) / (np.sum(norm_A) * np.sum(norm_B))


(this corresponds to dot producting the 768 dim vectors against each other than summing the list of 1214 dot product scores and normalizing)
I have tried several different compare_vecs implementations (e.g max, min, average, sum) and a few different layer indicies from which I grab the features (last layer, first layer, third layer)... nothing seems to really output anything that is "wow".
I feel like I'm kind of shooting in the dark here and have a few questions:

How does the AST handle different song lengths? It seems that when you extract features from the raw array of sound data the output is always (1, 1024, 128) -- what happens that the audio file length is normalized to a fixed dimension spectogram? (I couldn't find this on the original paper)

What impact does this have on how we compare feature vectors? Could I be comparing a very squished song against a very stretched song and getting total garbage?

Which hidden layers should I be using to extract the features from?

How should I actually be comparing the features mathematically?


